# I Have a problem with understanding some Java code

Tags: java

The Code:

```
package com.keyoti.rapidSpell;

import java.util.Comparator;

// Referenced classes of package com.keyoti.rapidSpell:
//            RapidSpellChecker

class RapidSpellChecker$CompareL
    implements Comparator
{

    public int compare(Object a, Object b)
    {
        return (int)(100D * (suggestionScore2b(topWord, (String)b) - suggestionScore2b(topWord, (String)a)));
    }

    public void with(String w)
    {
        topWord = w;
    }

    private String topWord;

    RapidSpellChecker$CompareL()
    {
    }
}
```

This is the one the many classes in the application.

What does the `$` sign in `class RapidSpellChecker$CompareL implements Comparator` signify?Is it simply the class name or has some significance?

Comment: Those question are some of the basic concepts in Java.
Try reading this book first: http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ4

Comment: is this a Java code or a decompiled class code?

Comment: And you are sure that this is not a decompiled code? ;)

Comment: Andrei: I disagree that knowing how class names look after compiling qualifies as a basic concept in Java. You also don't know how a C++ compiler does name mangling, usually.

Comment: @Andrei: You think that knowing the separator used by the compiler for nested classes is a "basic concept" in Java? I disagree.

Comment: @Jon and @Joey: I am sorry, but when I first saw the question I thought he asked what does `implements Comparator` mean. Also, I specified that `some` of the concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is decompiled code. (See at the bottom for more information.) The $ shows that it's a *nested class* within `RapidSpellChecker`. So the code would originally have looked something like this:

```
public class RapidSpellChecker
{
    // Other code withing RapidSpellChecker

    static class CompareL implements Comparator
    {
        // Code for compare, with etc
    }
}
```

I've shown this as a *static* nested class, because the code you've shown doesn't have any implicit reference to an instance of `RapidSpellChecker`. If it did, the original code would have been like this:

```
public class RapidSpellChecker
{
    // Other code withing RapidSpellChecker

    class CompareL implements Comparator
    {
        // Code for compare, with etc
    }
}
```

In this case it's an *inner class*.

See the [Java tutorial on nested classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more information.

---

EDIT: I originally thought this was invalid code; that you couldn't use $ in an identifier in Java to start with. It turns out I'm wrong. From the [Java Language Specification, section 3.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8):

> The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access preexisting names on legacy systems.

So it's valid, just discouraged.

Comment: It is valid code actually (or at least it compiles for me)- you can use $ as a variable name if you want.

Comment: Yes it is decompiled code......
and after making the the changes you suggested I am still getting and error because the class RapidSpellChecker has already been defined....

Comment: @Abhimanyu: What do you mean by "inherited in the package"? I'm talking about what the original source code would look like - it would have the contents of both RapidSpellChecker and CompareL in the same source file.

Comment: @jon...I am trying to implement a spell checker in my web application.
RapidSpellChecker class has already been defined...Its quite a big class...so won't be able to paste it here...
it simply perform different functions needed to implement a apellchecker...

Comment: @Abhimanyu: It sounds like RapidSpellChecker is a library which you should be trying to integrate, rather than reverse engineering the source code...

Comment: @jon...you got this right...actually i m trying to go through the code so that if possible i can implement some new feature and more importantly i would like to see it running...I m using eclipse but a few file are showing error and i m trying to rectify them..

Comment: @Abhimanyu: Are you legally *allowed* to decompile this code? If so, are you sure you can't just get the original source code instead?

Comment: @Jon...i downloaded the demo version and it contains the jar file which contain the .class file...so all i did is decompiled them to see what is actually being done inside.....i guess thats not illegal????

Comment: @Jon...can you atleast suggest where can i get a good tutorial on how to integrate libraries into my web application.....I would highly appreciate the help......

Comment: You decompile a demo version of a (supposidly) commercial library with the intend of copying the source and stitching a few things on along the way. I guess stricly speaking it depends on your country of residence if this is truely illegal, and on your purpose for this endevear. I doubt they are honorable tbh though.

Comment: @Steven..Not really am i trying to make a spell checker of my own....i m simply trying to learn how it works...if its possible to make such a big deal of it then i guess i cannot get help anywhere on net???

Comment: Well your question was answered, you asked what the $ means and it was explained to you. Now you ask something totally different, namely "how to integrate libraries into your web application". This is completely unrelated, a very broad question, and one that you can easily google yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That's a nested class. When the Java compiler compiles a class with nested classes, it separates all of them in different .class files.

```
class A {
  class B {
  }
}
```

gives A.class and A$B.class

Comment: @Xr...oke....got it...but since i m using a decompiled code,so make this code run...what changes i will have to make???

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$` in a variable name if you want.  In a variable name it has no special significance.

`$` is also typically used to indicate inner classes when you compile using `javac`

If you compile

```
class A {
    class B {
    }
}
```

You'll see A.class created and B.class.

For fun and amusement, you could create confusing looking "JQuery"-esque code in Java (you need the static import to use the `$` static method).  See the example below:

```
import static thisPackage.*;

public class $ {
    public static $ $(String s) { return new $(s); }
    public $ fadeIn(int fade) { return this; }
    public $ slideUp(int slide) { return this; }
    public $ delay(int ms) { return this; }
    public $(String s) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       $("#foo").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
    }
}
```

Implementing this with a DOM library underneath would be a fun project!